# How to pass local storage item to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to pass an array of strings from my local storage (key value) to MVC controller. Here's my code:

In cshtml View file:

```
 <script>

        function getFavouriteBooks() {
            var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));
            // returns: ["1", "2", "3"]

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                url: '@Url.Action("Favourites", "Home")',
                data: { ids: ids },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.Result);
                }
            }});
        }
    </script>


   <button onClick="getFavouriteBooks()">Display Favourites</button>
```

My controller:

```
public async Task < ViewResult > Favourites(string ids) {
    // code that fetches book data from API 

    if (data != null)

    {
        var bookList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Book[] > (data);

        foreach(var book in bookList) {
            var matches = new List < bookList > ();
            if (bookList.All(book => ids.Contains(book.Id))) {
                matches.Add(book);
            }

            return View("Index", matches.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return View("Index");
}
```

The controller action gets called successfully on the button click but the ids parameter is always null even though it isn't when in the console. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @SandipBantawa, it's a POST, body is fine. Try changing ids in your Action to a `string[]`. eg. `public ViewResult Favourites(string[] ids)`. BTW you're not using `async` or `Task`, might be better to remove those from the signature.

Comment: set your data up like this...     data: JSON.stringify(ids)   .... And then change your MVC method to Favourites(string[] ids)  .... let MVC do the work of deserializing the JSON data coming in

Comment: Thanks @CallumMorrisson I have tried this but it's an empty string

Comment: Favourites([FromBody]string[] ids) will fix that. This will tell MVC to pull that data out of the POST body instead of the URL route data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help everyone, the solution was actually to change this part of the ajax call to:

`data: { ids: localStorage.getItem('videoIds') },`

Answer (score 0):

from what you have described, I strongly feel this is the problem of expecting asynchronous function to behave synchronously,

```
await foreach(var book in bookList) {
            var matches = new List < bookList > ();
            if (bookList.All(book => ids.Contains(book.Id))) {
                matches.Add(book);
            }

            return View("Index", matches.ToArray());
        }
```

Try adding await before you call foreach loop. or better use for in loop

Comment: @hououinkyoma the await is to do with the API call to retrieve the booklist - I have await code in there already

Comment: @Jordan1993 Try then back  var ids= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds")); instead of localStorage.getItem("bookIds");

Comment: @Sergey sorry, what do you mean? My code is already `var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));`

Comment: @Jordan1993, yes that might be the case, but this problem is very common where we can see the thing in console but displaying in UI, mostly it has to do with asynchronous behavior of code. try running debugger over it if it shows in debugger than we can futher inspect

Comment: Sorry, I updated my answer. Since I don't know how you fiiled local storage ids, I have to guess.

Comment: Can you show the code  you used to put ids in a local storage pls? or what ids are like when you use var ids= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));

Comment: @Sergey, when I do var ids= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds")); I get `["1", "2", "3"]`

Comment: Ok , good. It should go to the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

This code was tested in Visual Studio.

You have to create a viewModel:

```
public class IdsViewModel
    {
         public string[] Ids { get; set; }
    }
```

Replace this:

```
  var ids = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));
            // returns: ["1", "2", "3"]
// or you can  use 
var ids = localStorage.getItem('videoIds');  //it still will be working


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                url: '@Url.Action("Favourites", "Home")',
                data: { ids: ids },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
```

with this

```
var ids= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookIds"));

  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: '/Home/Favourites',
   data: { ids:ids },
 success: function (result) {
....
```

and the action

```
public async Task <ActionResult> Favourites(IdsViewModel viewModel) {

var ids=viewModel.Ids;

.....
```

Comment: thank you but unfortunately ids is still an empty string :/

Comment: @Jordan1993 Sorry for your time, but I updated my answer. It was tested in VS. – Sergey 50 secs ago   Edit   Delete